# django debug mode sends uploaded files to "upload_to" directory in STATIC_ROOT

Tags: django, debugging, static

Looked at some other similar answers on stack overflow, but no relevant answer was found.

```
STATIC_ROOT = /home/www/proj_a/static
MEDIA_ROOT = /home/www/proj_a/media
STATIC_URL = /static/
MEDIA_URL = /media/
```

in some class in some model, we have the upload_to set

```
pix = models.FileField(_('photo'), upload_to='upload', blank=True)
```

I would have expected the file to be sent to **/media/upload/1.jpg**
However, it ends up in **/static/upload/1.jpg**

This is not lining up with my understanding of docs on Django 1.3.

I am using Django 1.3 in Debug mode.

I am not using Apache yet, I'll worry about it later, for now I am just trying to figure out the **runserver** issue in debug mode.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom storage directory by doing something like this:

```
upload_dir = FileSystemStorage(location=UPLOAD_ROOT, base_url='/uploads')
pix = models.FileField(_('photo'), upload_to='/upload', blank=True, storage=upload_dir)
```

UPLOAD_ROOT is defined in my settings.py file: /path/www/upload

Check these 2 pages for more details:

http://abing.gotdns.com/posts/2009/django-file-upload-handling-examples/

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/

Comment: django is famous for its DRY-ness. I rather not work on something that django supports out of the box. I think the whole MEDIA_ROOT vs STATIC_ROOT is the source of confusion and they were introduced in 1.3 I think. Or do I really need to go the route as mentioned above?

Comment: upload_to is not recommeded to start with "/". It will give you headaches later.